# OLS Regression equation

Tags: regression, least-squares, predictor

This question is primarily for my understanding; say we have a regression equation of the form **Y = Xb**, where **X** is a matrix of a few explanatory variables. If you are told that the vector **'b'** does not exist, would this equation still have any value? Does it mean we are seeing a non-linear relationship between **X** and **Y**?

Thank you!

Comment: More context, please. You’re always allowed to pick a **b** vector such that the matrix multiplication works out, so **b** not existing seems like nonsense to me unless there is additional information. (Such a **b** chosen at random is unlikely to be useful, sure, but it exists.)

Comment: I definitely agree that we need context here (and I think it should have been closed until the question was clarified). However I am confused by the additional comment. If Y and X are given, I am not sure we can always pick a $b$ to make the  equation $Y=Xb$ true. How would we do that? Of course if you add in an error term you have lots of d.f. to play with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would start with the assumption that b doesn't exist.

Regardless of whether or not the relationship between Y and the X variables is linear, it is usually possible to find a value for the vector b (exceptions might be related to [multi-collinearity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity) and non-invertibility of X'X).

This is "just" linear algebra: we are finding a set of values such that Y is projected onto the "column space" of X in a way that minimizes the error. A good reference on this is Agresti's [Foundations of linear and generalized linear models](https://www.wiley.com/en-ca/Foundations+of+Linear+and+Generalized+Linear+Models-p-9781118730034)

So in summary, even if b existed and was calculated, you can't immediately conclude that a linear model is the best option here. On the other hand, if b can't be calculated, you might have to drop variables from X before fitting and trying to assess whether the relationship is linear.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Wouldn't multi-collinearity indicate beta = 1/-1? What would happen if Beta was 0 in this case?

Comment: Hi Kiara, no, I would not expect there to be any reason why multi-collinearity would leat to a beta of 1 or -1. I don't think there is any specific relationship between multi-collinearity and specific values of beta.